# Scope of Global variables in Python in Windows

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I have a CLI script which I am using to push files into and s3 bucket.
For larger files i am splitting the files into parts and uploading them
in parallel. (Pasting code structure here. I tried to make a minimalist example but even that is 60 lines long)

```
def _upload_part(argFile, argBucket, max_attempts_limit, **core_chunk):
    #bunch of stuff
    pool = Pool(processes=parallel_processes)
    for i in range( chunk_amount ):
        #bunch of stuff
        pool.apply_async( _upload_for_multipart, [keyname, offset, mp, part_num, bytes] )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def _upload_for_multipart(keyname, offset, mp, part_num, bytes):
    #code to upload each part
    #log the status of each part to log files

def _get_logger( pdir, ldir, lname, level, fmt ):
    os.makedirs( logs_dir )
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=os.path.join(logs_dir, lname),
        level=level,
        format=fmt
    )
    return logging.getLogger( lname )

#under main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logneeds = dict( pdir=exec_dir, ldir='logs', lname='s3_cli.log', level='INFO',
                               fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s' )
    logger = _get_logger(**logneeds)
```

The above code structure works in OSX and Linux but fails in windows. It says that the 
`name 'logger' is not defined` under the `_upload_for_multipart` function .Is there a difference between the way global variables
are interpreted in windows and unix based OS?

Edit: Added working example [here](http://pastie.org/10112205)

Comment: It's difficult to debug code that isn't present.

Comment: @martineau -  I can post the code here, but I couldnt make it any smaller than 60 lines of code...

Comment: Well, you should at least include the section that has the line that results in the `name 'logger' is not defined` error. Some folks upload longish pieces of code onto a website like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or [GitHub](https://github.com) and include a url reference to it in their question.

Comment: @martineau - Pasting links to code isnt allowed on SO AFAIK and gets downvoted. People ask for a small example if code is too long

Comment: It's discouraged but people do it (paste links) anyway.

Comment: The idea given below works but i get the error `Nonetype attribute has no attribute error` . Could you help with that?

Comment: Sharing state (i.e. global variables) between processes is tricky and best avoided. Better to use `Queue`s and `Pipe`s to exchange data. If you must share data, the `multiprocessing` module supports `Value`s and `Array`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is a difference in the way child processes get created on Windows vs. UNIX-y OSes (or any OS that supports `fork`). On Linux, `fork` is used to create the child process, which creates the child in a copy-on-write duplicate of the parent process. That means all the variables present in the parent will be present in the child.

Windows, however, does not support `fork`. In order to create the child, it spawns a brand-new process, and then re-imports the `__main__` module of the parent in the child. In your case that means that the script running your program gets imported in the child. The creation of `logger` happens inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard in the parent, which means it gets skipped when the child imports the module. There are a couple of places in the `multiprocessing` docs that mention this, which I explicitly list in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29800947/2073595).

In order for `logger` to exist in the children, it needs to either get created at the top-level of the module (which would mean it runs every time you import it), or you need to explicitly create it in all the child processes, perhaps using the `initializer` argument to `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
logger = None

def init_log():
    global logger
    logneeds = dict(pdir=exec_dir, ldir='logs', lname='s3_cli.log', level='INFO',
                    fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s' )
    logger = _get_logger(**logneeds)

def _upload_part(argFile, argBucket, max_attempts_limit, **core_chunk):
    #bunch of stuff
    pool = Pool(processes=parallel_processes, initializer=init_log)
    for i in range( chunk_amount ):
        #bunch of stuff
        pool.apply_async( _upload_for_multipart, [keyname, offset, mp, part_num, bytes] )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def _upload_for_multipart(keyname, offset, mp, part_num, bytes):
    #code to upload each part
    #log the status of each part to log files

def _get_logger( pdir, ldir, lname, level, fmt ):
    os.makedirs( logs_dir )
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=os.path.join(logs_dir, lname),
        level=level,
        format=fmt
    )
    return logging.getLogger( lname )

#under main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_log()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. i followed your advise and your given code and made the necessary changes in my code. However the child process throws an error saying - `Nonetype object has no attribute  info`

Comment: @Beginner Can you edit your question to include a complete example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: - I added a link to the script after I got rid of 80% of the code.

Comment: @Beginner The problem is here:`Pool(processes=parallel_processes, initializer=init_log(logFile))`. You're using `initializer=init_log(logFile)`, which actually calls `init_log` in the parent process and passes the return value from that function to `initializer`. This means that `logger` isn't getting set up in the child at all. What you should be doing is just passing the `init_log` function to the child process, so that `logger` is actually set up in the child.  So, you should do this instead: `Pool(processes=parallel_processes, initializer=init_log, initargs=(logFile,))`

Comment: I had a feeling that passing `initializer = ini_log(logFile)` was not right. I fixed the issues. Now I run into a `permissionError`. I think this is a step forward